# Replace a specific profile field

Tags: profiles

I have a profile field which is called.

```
$user_meta->steam_steamid
```

I would like to get that fields value and replace it with the result i get from

```
echo getSteamId32($steamid64);
```

or

```
getSteamId32($steamid64);
```

The code i use but it doesnt replace that field.
https://pastebin.com/7U6Sn9cT

Comment: Where do you get `$user_meta` from? Can't you use [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)? How was this field added?

Comment: `<?php $user_meta = get_userdata(bp_get_member_user_id());echo($user_meta->steam_steamid);?>`<br>
Need more specific guide not just `use update_user_meta()`